# decrease mandatory parameters (change method signature) on overriden method best practices (i.e. to avoid pylint errors)

Tags: python, pylint

I have a generic parent class with mymethod and specific child class, where some parameters required for mymethod are known - user of child don't even need to know about them. I want to override mymethod so it only require param1, however pylint complains about inherited method changed signature -  W0221: Number of parameters was *** in *** and is now *** in overridden *** method (arguments-differ)

What's the best practice for this use case? I've tried adding **kwargs to either or both methods, but no help (even if it would I'd then have to work around 'unused arguments' issue?) I could create ChildA.mymethod2 with only accepting param1 and within it call super().mymethod(param1, param2, param3) filling remaining parameters, but that seems rather awkward - is there better way to achieve this?

```
class Parent():

    def mymethod(self, param1, param2, param3):  
        log.info(f'func a with {param1} and {param2} and {param3}')

class ChildA(Parent):

    def mymethod(self, param1, **kwargs):  # kwargs added hoping to 'fool' pylint about signature arguments, no help
        param2 = 2
        param3 = 3
        super().func(param1, param2, param3)
```

desired state is having Parent and numerous Child classes (each defining its own param2 and param3) passing pylint, while user can only do

```
c = ChildA()
c.mymethod(param1)
```

Comment: the best practice is *not to do that* which is why pylint is complaining. The most straightforward way is to use another method (it's really not akward, and pretty common, of course, you shouldn't just name it `method2` or whatever, but give it a meaningful name). But if you really want to do it, you can just ignore pylint.

Comment: What you're proposing to do is breaking the Liskov substitution principle, (L in SOLID) which means you won't be able to use child classes or parent interchangeably with the same calling code.

Comment: my specific situation is having a generic MongoBase class exposing numerous methods like find, insert, create, update and their variations, each requiring collection name as a parameter. MongoBase child classes are tied to particular collections in mongo and I'd like for each child to be able use any of the parent methods, but obviously without the need to specify collection anymore (ideally not even as optional parameter, not to confuse users) Also I'd like to keep MonoBase as is, to be actually able to operate on any collection submitted dynamically. Not sure how to proceed then?

Comment: Also, why *args or **kwargs doesn't work.? Does it not stand in for any number of parameters, but is it counted as 'one' in terms of signature? I.e. having parent.func(param1, param2,**kwargs) I can execute child.func(param1=1, param2=2, param3=3) but I cannot override it as def func(param1, **kwargs) ? (that is to hint user to provide only param1, deliberately hiding rest of params to simplify usage, while using **kwargs should ensure all parameters are equally accepted in both child and parent usage. (passing Liskov principle)

Answer (score 2):

You could try using default arguments in the child classes:

```
class Parent():
    def mymethod(self, param1, param2, param3):  
        log.info(f'func a with {param1} and {param2} and {param3}')

class ChildA(Parent):
    def mymethod(self, param1, param2=None, param3=None):
        param2 = 2
        param3 = 3
        super().func(param1, param2, param3)
```